# Is there a method to include dependency with provided scope in the FAT Jar

Tags: maven, maven-shade-plugin

I am using maven shade plugin to package a FAT jar. I have certain dependencies which are marked scope - provided, is there a way to include those as well in the FAT Jar?

Comment: If they should go into the fat jar, just change the scope to `compile`. Is there any reason you want them `provided`?

Comment: Yes, I don't want them to be packed as regular JAR. But for FAT jar I want them to be packed as JAR

Comment: In a regular jar, nothing is packed into the artifact. Could you give more details on what you are doing?